# Rotating a model around all 3 (X, Y, Z) axis in DirectX 11.2 C++

Tags: c++, rotation, axis, directx-11

I have the next problem. I am trying to rotate a 3D model around all 3 axis at the same time. Meaning i want to rotate the model around the X axis, then the Y axis, then again the X and so forth by pressing the buttons on the keyboard. The problem is when i use XMMatrixRotationX, XMMatrixRotationY or XMMatrixRotationZ like this:

```
    void Rotate(float radians_x, float radians_y, float radians_z)
    {
        DirectX::XMStoreFloat4x4(&_transfer.world, DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose(DirectX::XMMatrixRotationZ(radians_z)));
        DirectX::XMStoreFloat4x4(&_transfer.world, DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose(DirectX::XMMatrixRotationY(radians_y)));
        DirectX::XMStoreFloat4x4(&_transfer.world, DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose(DirectX::XMMatrixRotationX(radians_x)));
    }
```

only the last rotation gets done. I want to be able to rotate the object around each of the axis by a specific angle (actually, radians), as you can see in the code. I have found out that the XMMatrixRotationAxis method does this, but it only takes one angle parameter, and i want to use a different one for each axis. Can anyone help me about how can this be done?

Also, i don't know what to send as a first parameter to the XMMatrixRotationAxis, it just says a vector of axis. I don't understand how do i access those, the methods i used in the code posted don't need to be sent any axis. I dont understand why is this necessary, or how to do it, in case this is the right solution.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer here:

http://books.google.hr/books?id=7ZkLAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA251&lpg=PA251&dq=XMMatrixRotationQuaternion&source=bl&ots=xveQhsj-x_&sig=Ny6IdK1JNFBF99LyC_HY8b-y4tI&hl=hr&sa=X&ei=dtkQVOmmA8aXatfugZgL&ved=0CHEQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=XMMatrixRotationQuaternion&f=false

I have to use the XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw. The code now looks:

```
    void Rotate(float radians_x, float radians_y, float radians_z)
    {
        DirectX::XMStoreFloat4x4(&_transfer.world, DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose(DirectX::XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw(radians_x, radians_y, radians_z)));
    }
```

Works like a charm :)